# Return text in cell if part of text is found in a specific row

Tags: excel, windows, excel-formula

I have data organized like this:

```
01AENPRV__  -0166U  -289R   -127PT  
ABGIKLOPPUX___  -05AP   -2244U      
13AABDDEFFGMMM  -115HU  -2339U      
14AABBDFFGMMMOP -1234U  -015MU      
12ACDFFGHMMNOP  -117JU  -2345R  -457JU  
AGIJPRSTT___    -133U   -011J       
$144778N    -1335U  -1235R      
$0001123N   -1118FU -125R       
$013899N    -1278R  -058AU      
0169CKLRT____   -345U   -1249R  -015BP  
ABCIKKLP    -57GP   -0144R
```

I would like to search a specific row across multiple columns for cells that contain "R" and return the whole text.

For example:
search the row 12ACDFFGHMMNOP is in and return -2345R

I have tried Vlookup, but that only works if the values are organized in specific columns, which in this data set it will not be.

Comment: How do you determine the **specific row** to search? Where are these results being returned? Please edit your question to include what you have tried, and explain how what you have tried isn't providing the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions

- Your table is a structured **Table** named `Table13`
- `searchrow` is a named cell containing the entry from the first column defining the row you wish to search
- `findtext` is a named cell containing the Text you wish to search for
- Since your tags did not specify otherwise, you have the latest release version of Excel

the following should work:

```
=LET(
    d, Table13,
    sc, CHOOSECOLS(d, 1),
    sr, CHOOSEROWS(
        DROP(d, , 1),
        MATCH(searchrow, sc, 0)
    ),
    f, FILTER(
        sr,
        ISNUMBER(FIND(findtext, sr))
    ),
    f
)
```

***Original Table***
[image]

***Selection Criteria and Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really show the purpose or expected result, I figured this may come handy:

`=TOCOL(REPT(A1:A11&B1:D11,1/(RIGHT(B1:D11)="R")),2)`

Or if your search value is in `B1`:

`=TOCOL(REPT(A1:A11&B1:D11,1/(RIGHT(B1:D11,LEN(F1))=F1)),2)`

[image]